# Webservice testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to `JMeter` and I have been tasked to do a POC where I need to load test the webserivce. I learnt the basics like adding the test plan, adding threads, adding `SOAP/RPC Request`sampler and I got the response as well. But, I am not sure how to achieve the below scenario using `JMeter`.

I need `600` users to hit the service `per request/second` (this should run for 10 minutes) and the 2nd scenario is about `2000` users to hit the service at `5 request/second` (again this should run for 10 minutes)

Also, would it be possible for JMeter to handle this many number of threads/users?

Any inputs would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you properly configure JMeter it shouldn't be a problem to simulate 2k users, actually you may need more as if your web service response time will exceed 1 second - you won't be able to achieve 2k requests per second.

1. Configuring JMeter:

   - Run test in non-GUI mode
   - Disable all Listeners (if any)
   - Increase JVM Heap size

   See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for detailed explanation and instructions
2. Simulating 600 / 2000 requests per second.

   - Set "Loop Count" to `Forever` or `-1` in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
   - Tick "Scheduler" box and set desired duration (`600` seconds)
   - Add [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) and specify the desired throughput in requests per minute
3. It is recommended to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for web services testing, you can set Content-Type and SOAPAction headers using [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Comment: thank you...will give a try tomorrow...thanks for ur suggestions!

Comment: how do I configure "2000 users to hit the service at 5 request/second". I am confused with 5 req/second. Where do I set this? Is this configurable?

Comment: I've mentioned the [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer). Add it to your Test Plan and configure "Target Throughput" to be `300` requests per minute (5 requests * 60 seconds).